# Role command DiscordJS V13

Tags: discord.js

If the user does not have the role, it will add the role, but if the user already has the role, it will remove the role. How can I do that?

```
    if (message.member.roles.has(role.id)){
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#5865F2')
        .setDescription(`Role added ${role} to ${member}.`)
        .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}`)
    
        member.roles.remove(role.id)
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    } else {
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#5865F2')
        .setDescription(`Role removed ${role} to ${member}.`)
        .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}`)
    
        member.roles.add(role.id)
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you get when you run the code? Any unexpected behaviour?

Comment: ```message.member.roles.has is not a function``` This is the error I always get. How can I fix this mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because the `.has()` function does not exist in the `roles` property. Instead, you need to fetch them using `.fetch()` or use the cached roles by using `roles.cache.has()`. So your code might look something like this:

```js
if (message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id)){
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#5865F2')
        .setDescription(`Role added ${role} to ${member}.`)
        .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}`)
    
    member.roles.remove(role.id)
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
} else {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#5865F2')
        .setDescription(`Role removed ${role} to ${member}.`)
        .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}`)
    
    member.roles.add(role.id)
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
}
```

Comment: A new error has appeared and it says ``DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions``

Comment: That probably means that your bot doesn't have permission to add/remove roles or it is trying to add/remove a role from a user who has a higher positioned role than the bot

Comment: The bot has all the permission and it has the highest role, but the error is still there.

Comment: Can you add the complete error as it might show where the error originated from?

Comment: If the answer has solved your problem, please accept the answer as it will help people to see the correct solution for your problem